Does seq() have rounding errors?
Why does seq() has some problems when going through 0?
Why does seq() not handle the following?
seq(-1.2, 0, by = 0.2)   # [1] -1.2 -1.0 -0.8 -0.6 -0.4 -0.2  0.0
seq(-1.2, 0.2, by = 0.2) # [1] -1.200000e+00 -1.000000e+00 -8.000000e-01 -6.000000e-01 -4.000000e-01 -2.000000e-01  2.220446e-16  2.000000e-01


The problem is that floating point numbers aren't that precise. If you do everything with integers and divide at the end it's more stable. seq(-12, 0, by = 2)/10 and seq(-12, 2, by = 2)/10, for example. The value of 0.2 is just hard for computers to store exactly as a floating point number.
